# ReactJS Redux Persist isn't showing my reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

for some reason - i cannot see my reducers when i console.log(this.props). I did a purge every time i reload the app to reset this current redux state. I can't even view the INITIAL_STATE default values. Below is my HOC containing the router, provider, and persist gate. Also are the reducer (reducers/index.js) and store configuration file (store/index.js)

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {store, persistor} from './store/index';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import App from './App';

import './i18n';
persistor.purge()
console.log("purged")
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <App/>
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

store/index.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage' // defaults to localStorage for web and AsyncStorage for react-native

import rootReducer from '../reducers/index'

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'primary',
  storage,
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer)

const middleware = applyMiddleware()

const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  middleware
)
const persistor = persistStore(store)

export {store, persistor}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

export const SETJWT = 'auth/login/setJWT'

let INITAL_STATE = {
    JWT: 'testJWT',
    currentUser: null,
    isLoggingIn: false
}

const rootReducer = (state = INITAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case SETJWT:
            return {...state, JWT: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following like to my createstore

```
combineReducers({
      state: persistedReducer
  }),
```